# Exporting database from phpmyadmin

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, export

When I export the database from phpmyadmin in CSV format, all the fields are stored in the first columns ? How do I get them each in different column ? I tried FIELDS ESCAPED BY \ and LINES TERMINATED BY \r\n but doesnt work
Thanks

Comment: not sure what you are trying to say... you mean you want to export as tab separated?

Comment: All the fields of database gets exported in the first column of .csv file. While I want each field in a different column.

Comment: oh, are you trying to open it in excel? I think you need to specify you want a comma as a separator (excel by default expects the separator to be a semi column)

Comment: Fields terminated by ,
Fields enclosed by "
Fields escaped by \
Lines terminated by \r\n
Replace NULL by NULL

Comment: yeah im opening it in excel

Comment: try either changing the separator to ; on export or making sure you specify the comma as separator when opening it